# "it's high time"+past simple vs. "should have"+past participle

Tags: grammar

1. Can we use "it's high time" + past simple interchangeably with "should have" + past participle?

*It's high time you revised your lessons* VS. *you should have revised your lessons*

2.Do these sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Hello Fouad_B, and welcome to ELL. Please have a read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What's missing from your question here is your research. Please [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/329236/edit) your question to tell us what you already know about these expressions. What do you think "it's high time" means? What do you think "you should have" means? Also, your questions 1 and 2 have the same meaning. If you meant to ask two different things, please change one of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your two bullet points in one:

Yes, both phrases are correct and mean pretty much the same, except they do not express the same *urgency*. This you could fix appending “by  now” to the latter.

> It's high time you revised your lessons

[Mariam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%27s%20high%20time): “It's high time.”: used to say it is time to do something that should have been done a long time ago

<sup>btw. High time or highest time is very similar to the German expression “Hoechste Zeit”</sup>

> you should have revised your lessons by now

[Grammarhow](https://grammarhow.com/by-now-meaning-usage/): The phrase “by now” is a common way to talk about how things might come to an end at the present time.